# Compiled with problems: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for builtin components) or a class/function (for composite components)got undefind

Tags: reactjs

I am doing a react portfolio project .
This is my about.jsx  code

```
import React from 'react'
import {Tilt} from "react-tilt";
import {motion} from 'framer-motion';
 

import { services } from '../constants';
import {fadeIn,textVariant} from "../utils/motion"
import {SectionWrapper} from "../hoc"
import { styles } from '../styles';

const ServiceCard =({index,title,icon})=>{
  return (
    <Tilt className="xs:w-[250px] w-full">
      <motion.div variants={fadeIn("right","spring", 0.5 *index,0.75)} 
        className='w-full green-pink-gradient p-[1px] rounded-[20px] shadow-card'>
          <div options={{
            max:45,
            scale:1,
            speed:450
          }} className='bg-tertiary rounded-[20px] py-5 px-12 min-h-[280px]
            flex justify-evenly items-center flex-col'>
              <img src={icon} alt={title}
                className='w-16 h-16 object-contain'/>
              <h3>{title}</h3>

          </div>
      </motion.div>
    </Tilt>
  )
}

const About = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <motion.div variants={textVariant()}>
        <p className={styles.sectionSubText}>Introduction</p>
        <h2 className={styles.sectionHeadText}>Overview</h2>
      </motion.div>
      <motion.p variants={fadeIn("","",0.1,1)} 
        className='mt-4 text-secondary text-[17px] max-w-3xl leading-[30px]'>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Vitae, voluptate accusamus earum distinctio est sequi, deserunt, necessitatibus voluptatem quidem modi illum neque ad deleniti! Laudantium repellat autem facilis reiciendis iusto voluptatem, error consequatur quo libero rerum impedit delectus consectetur repudiandae repellendus molestiae debitis odio assumenda accusamus sed incidunt distinctio reprehenderit officia inventore. Officia velit maxime quod, quia quasi officiis quidem eligendi voluptates modi! Sapiente quidem fugiat soluta modi illo cupiditate.
      </motion.p>
      <div className='flex mt-20 flex-wrap gap-10'>
        {services.map((service,index)=>(
          <ServiceCard key={service.title} index={index} {...service} />
        ))}

      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default SectionWrapper(About ,"about")
```

Here I want to do some different thing to make my project unique but I face problem
here is my sectionWrapper code

```
import React from 'react'
import {motion} from "framer-motion";
import {styles} from "../styles"
import { staggerContainer } from '../utils/motion';

const SectionWrapper = (Component,idName) => {
function HOC(){
    return (
        <motion.section
            variants={staggerContainer()}
            initial="hidden"
            whileInView="show"
            viewport={{once:true,amount:0.25}}
            className={`${styles.padding} max-w-7xl mx-auto relative z-0`}
        >
            <span className='hash-span' id={idName}>&nbsp;</span>
            <Component/>
        </motion.section>
        )
    }
}

export default SectionWrapper;
```

and here I want to export SectionWrapper ```import SectionWrapper from "./SectionWrapper";

export {SectionWrapper}```
but I get error But in terminal it don't say error .It shows error in webpage .
The error msg is

```
Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check the render method of `App`.
    at createFiberFromTypeAndProps (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43038:21)
    at createFiberFromElement (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:43059:19)
    at updateElement (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31584:23)
    at updateSlot (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31677:26)
    at reconcileChildrenArray (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:31823:26)
    at reconcileChildFibers (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:32210:20)
    at reconcileChildren (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35149:32)
    at updateHostComponent (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:35786:7)
    at beginWork (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:37231:18)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:22217:18)[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```